# Cython3 Using Threading.Thread with args inside the class

Tags: python-3.x, cython, python-multithreading

Cython,Support me on this error...I have shown the example code and error generated in my code.I'm using Anaconda3 latest distribution for windows, How to use Thread with args inside the class

```
#cytest.pyx
from threading import Thread

cdef class t(object):

    cdef int a,b,nthreads
    cpdef readonly list retlist

    def __init__(self,int nthreads,int a=10,int b=10):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.retlist = []
        self.nthreads = nthreads

    cdef mul(self,int c,int d):
        cdef int n
        n = (self.a*c)+(self.b*d)
        self.retlist.append(n)

    cpdef run_mul(self):
        cdef int i
        cdef object Thd
        for i in range(self.nthreads):
           Thd = Thread(target=self.mul, args=(10,20))
           # Note: I got error in above arguments
           Thd.start()
```

Above file cytest.pyx compiled and imported as below..

```
import cytest
ts = cytest.t(4)
```

while run the following code I got error as below

```
ts.run_mul()
```

Error as below....How to resolve this problem in cython

```
Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "stringsource", line 65, in 
cfunc.to_py.__Pyx_CFunc_object____t____int____int___to_py.wrap
TypeError: wrap() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (2 given)

Exception in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "stringsource", line 65, in 
cfunc.to_py.__Pyx_CFunc_object____t____int____int___to_py.wrap
TypeError: wrap() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (2 given)

Exception in thread Thread-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "stringsource", line 65, in 
cfunc.to_py.__Pyx_CFunc_object____t____int____int___to_py.wrap
TypeError: wrap() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (2 given)

Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "stringsource", line 65, in 
cfunc.to_py.__Pyx_CFunc_object____t____int____int___to_py.wrap
TypeError: wrap() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the function `def` instead of `cdef`.

It helps to think about why you're making a function `cdef`. The only real difference in a `cdef` function is that you're saying it can only be called at a C level, and so you can avoid the Python calling mechanism. In this case you're trying to pass it as a callable Python object to a Python function, which is utterly meaningless.

(Cython tries to help you a bit by wrapping it with a Python layer, but this is a bit buggy and doesn't deal with the bound `self` correctly. You might want to report it as a bug at https://github.com/cython/cython/issues.)

Comment: Can I make self as a argument inside parentheses as ..args = (self,10,20). It works for me in my trials

Comment: Maybe. But just use  `def` function. There's absolutely no reason not to. `cdef` _will not_ be any faster in this case.

Comment: @endermaz I suggest you ask a new question. I don't see why it wouldn't work but there can be complications to Cython+threading (mostly that it doesn't release the GIL by itself unless prompted)